# Pass variable from outside to query used in a Neo4j apoc.do.case procedure

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

So I am writing a trigger which looks at a certain type of relationship and gets the start and end node of this relationship. Additionally another node is matched.

What the trigger should do depends on a condition that is why I need to use apoc.do.case. So for the condition as well as the query the variables for the nodes have to be accessed. In the condition that seems to work just fine which i tested with different queries for the conditions. But in the queries as displayed below the variables cannot be accessed which I tested by accessing one node by id to see what gets created. The problem is node o does not get selected as matched before but rather gets created completely new as an empty node. ( When using this query for the first condition: Match (c) where id(c) = 62 CREATE (c)-[:is_a]->(o) )

So my problem is to access the variables from outside in apoc.do.case

I know that it is possible to use input parameters or another with statement inside apoc.do.case but I already tried different approaches but did not get it right.

Maybe someone knows how to do it

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('Update drinking',
"UNWIND [rel in $createdRelationships WHERE type(rel) = 
'has_alcohol_comsumption'] AS rel 
WITH startNode(rel) AS start, endNode(rel) AS end MATCH 
(o:customer{label:'drinker'}) CALL apoc.do.case( [end.label <> 'Never'  and
not((start)-[:is_a]->(o)), 'CREATE (start)-[:is_a]->
(o)', end.label ='Never' and((start)-[:is_a]->(o)), 'MATCH (start)-
[rel2:is_a]->(o)  DETACH DELETE rel2' ]) YIELD value return value", 
{phase:'before'});
```

To understand the problem it is enough to create a few nodes:

```
create(rarely:occurrence_frequency{label:'Rarely'})
create(never:occurrence_frequency{label:’Never'})
create(christina:customer{label:'Christina',has_name:'Christina'})
create(drinker:customer{label:’drinker'})
Match (n:customer {label:'Christina'}) Match (x:occurrence_frequency {label:'Never'}) Create (n)-[:has_alcohol_comsumption]->(x)
```

So at the beginning Christina does not drink alcohol but the Node drinker and Rarely do exist. When we change the alcohol consumption as in the following a is_a relationship to drinker should get created. And the other way around, when we change the consumption from rarely to never the is_a relationship should get deleted (which works but ALL is_a relationships are getting deleted).

```
Match (n:customer {label:'Christina'})-
[rel:has_alcohol_comsumption]->(m:occurrence_frequency 
{label:'Never'}) Match (o:occurrence_frequency 
{label:'Rarely'}) Call apoc.refactor.to(rel, o) Yield 
input, output Return input, output
```

I hope i did not forget something and my question is understandable.

Comment: please share us your input data and how to create sample subgraph. thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy I edited my question. That should be all you need to create the necessary nodes and one relationship at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the required parameters in `apoc.do.case`, try this:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
'Update drinking',
"UNWIND [rel in $createdRelationships WHERE type(rel) = 'has_alcohol_comsumption'] AS rel 
WITH startNode(rel) AS start, endNode(rel) AS end 
MATCH (o:customer{label:'drinker'}) 
CALL apoc.do.case(
[end.label <> 'Never' and not((start)-[:is_a]->(o)), 
'CREATE (start)-[:is_a]->(o)', 
end.label ='Never' and ((start)-[:is_a]->(o)),
'MATCH (start)-[rel2:is_a]->(o)  DETACH DELETE rel2' ],
'',
{start: start, end: end, o: o}) 
YIELD value return value", 
{phase:'before'}
);
```

Comment: ah ok, i knew that i had to do that somehow and came very close but used $ together with the variable name. It solved my problem so thanks!